# Show and hide menu icon in toolbar with Fragment in Android Studio

Tags: android, icons, android-toolbar

I am trying to use this code to show and hide menu icon in toolbar with Fragment in Android Studio:

```
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem IconBTON = menu.findItem(R.id.myIcon);

    if (statusBlueTooth == true){
        IconBTON.setVisible(true);
    }
    if (statusBlueTooth == false){
        IconBTON.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

but the icon is not shown even though the value of the flag statusBlueTooth = true, but just when I touch the toolbar the icon is shown, what do I need to do so that this is shown according to the value of flag statusBlueTooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this after in your onCreate of your Fragment:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and check `IconBTON != null` before setting the visibility.

Comment: I already did it as you recommend, but still the icon is still hidden, I have to click on the toolbar for it to show up

Comment: Try calling this after setting the boolean value `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();`